# Change Date format to YYYYMMDD

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I have this statement in my SQL Server Mgt Studio script. The Date output is `Dec 28 2015 12:00AM` etc. how to change it to `20151228` (`YYYYMMDD` format). Pls help. Thank you.

```
+'|'+ Cast(dateadd(wk,DATEDIFF(Wk,7,GETDATE()),0) as varchar) AS [FIRSTDAY|],
+'|'+ CAST(DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),6)AS varchar) as [LASTTDAY|]
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt at this yourself?

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you using? SQL Server **2012** and newer have a [`FORMAT` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) which you could use: `FORMAT(SYSDATETIME(), 'yyyyMM');`

Answer (score 3):

[Prior to Sql Server 2012:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
CONVERT(varchar(8), dateadd(wk,DATEDIFF(Wk,7,GETDATE()),0), 112)
```

[Sql Server 2012 and later:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

```
FORMAT(dateadd(wk,DATEDIFF(Wk,7,GETDATE()),0), 'yyyyMMdd')
```

But you should really ask yourself if SQL is the correct place to do this at all. You'll often have better results by just returning a `DateTime` value and letting client code handle the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Use the convert function instead of cast. Use style 112. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
declare @dt nvarchar(50) = 'Dec 28 2015 12:00AM'

select convert(varchar(4),datepart(yy,@dt))+convert(varchar(2),datepart(mm,@dt))+convert(varchar(2),datepart(dd,@dt))
```